# i18n dynamic translation in notion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization, notion-api

I was about getting the information in notion like blog
and I have translation in my local from en to ch,
how can I translate this code cause this one is from notion website/api

sample code

```
{post.title}
```

when I have translation from local string it is like this

```
{t('news')}
```